# Am I abusing ng-init?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-init, ng-init

I have two ng-repeats, one nested inside another, and I have a function I want to run after the **last** item has rendered.

Current I have it working as follows:

```
 <tr ng-repeat="requestResult in vm.$scope.requestResults">
     <td ng-repeat="column in vm.$scope.columns" ng-show="column.checked">
        <div ng-if="$parent.$last && $last" ng-init="$parent.$last && $last ?vm.finishedRendering():null"></div>
```

The issue with this implementation is that upon peer-review it was brought up that this was ngInit abuse. So my question for you guys is, is it? And if so how can I accomplish it correctly?

currently using 1.7.x angular

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit#

Comment: Most probably, yes, as the big red section of the documentation page you linked to indicates. Why do you need to run anything after something has been rendered? What is the concrete problem you're trying to solve? A template should call method to get data to display, or to react to a user event. Triggering side-effects after some loop is done is a big smell.

Comment: @JBNizet the reason is because we want to close the "loading modal" after the rendering happens. If we close it after we get the data, it closes the modal and takes takes forever to render large data sets leaving users confused as to what's happening. What is a correct way to approach this?

Comment: If it takes forever to just *render* data, then figure out why, and fix the problem. It shouldn't take more than a few milliseconds. Either you're actually measuring the time it takes to *download* the data (in that case, close the mocal after the download is finished), or you're rendering far too many data (and you should use pagination or other similar techniques, or your templating code does too far too many computations (and you should figure out why it does them).

Comment: If, temporarily, you want to keep it as is (i.e. live with this ultra-slow rendering), then just use $timeout from your controller to close the modal.

Comment: @JBNizet it's 1000 items multiplied by around 8,9 td elements. I dont know if that's considered too much data. But that's all it does. No computation once the data is retrieved. All we do is set requestResults to our new data. 

Do you have any hints/tips on figuring out why it takes that long?

Comment: It is certainly too much. Use pagination, or other rendring on scroll techniques, or a search.

Comment: @JBNizet ok thank you, that certainly helps!